# Open WhatsApp conversation using Abid doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, whatsapp, url-scheme

I'm trying to open whatsapp conversation/chat for particular contact.
Instead of opening the desired chat it only opens the app.
No idea whats wrong  :

```
 let URLString  = "whatsapp://send?abid=\(ID);text=lOL;"
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: URLString)!)
```

URLString value : `whatsapp://send?abid=414;text=lOL`

**Any suggestions?**

Comment: So it only open the App?

Comment: It just open whatsapp without any relation to the abid, like showing the main page of the app @LGL

Comment: Where is the API for that? can you please show me?

Comment: @LGL Dharmesh Figure It out lol , Thank you anyway brother

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Thank you mean , post your answer so i can accept it

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Nice, I knew it would be the API lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your `URL` like this:

```
whatsapp://send?abid=\(ID)&text=lOL
```

Source from [HERE](https://www.macstories.net/tutorials/use-whatsapps-url-scheme-with-drafts-launch-center-pro-or-a-bookmarklet/).

Comment: Hi, What is ID? I tried user name but it doesn't work!

Comment: The ABID (ABRecordID) is the integer that identifies the record. You can check the doc https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABRecordRef_iPhoneOS/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/ABRecordID

Comment: I tried it in iOS 9.3.1 and it doesn't work. The whatsapp show me the Select Contact panel. Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: @dcorbatta I have same problem. But no solutions for now :(

Comment: @dcorbatta I have same problem. Found no info about it till now.

Comment: We have to try to contact with Whatsapp. What is the dev support email?

Comment: It no longer works on iOS 9.0.2 I think WhatsApp killed the functionality, we need to contact the dev support team and find out if it was on purpose !.

Comment: I sent them a question and waiting a response, the following used to work and it stopped with the most recent update: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?abid=%d&text=%@", abid, @""]]];

Comment: WhatsApp could have renamed abid into something else or completely got rid of it. !

Comment: @Will Do you have news?

Comment: Hi, Yes I am not sure what was wrong but there is nothing wrong with WhatsApp, it was only resolved after a restore, or it started working again by itself. It was a really crazy situation. !

Answer (score 1):

Try this and check if the `UIApplication` and open the URL.

```
let whatsAppURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?abid=\(ID)&text=lOL")
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(whatsAppURL){
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(whatsAppURL)
}
```