# Whatsapp sharing doesn't work on IOS

Tags: ios, whatsapp, sharing, gluon

I'm developing an app across Gluon Mobile plugin on JavaFX and I integrated a whatsapp sharing, but when I try to use it on IOS doesn't work, on Android device the list of whatsapp contacts are displayed and the function works correctly.
To implement that, after some researches,I added on .plist file this key:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
          <string>whatsapp</string>
```

and     I used this code to open whatsapp from browser:

```
String whatsappUrl = "whatsapp://send?text=\\"; service.launchExternalBrowser(whatsappUrl+ myUrl);
```

where myUrl is the url that I want to join by whatsapp.

Can anyone helps to solve this problem on IOS?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you use the ABID for whatsapp sharing.

Comment: @DeepakSaki can you explain me what is and how I use this ABID?Thank you

Comment: please find the url  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32788744/open-whatsapp-conversation-using-abid-doesnt-work

Comment: @DeepakSaki I don't think is my case, I don't want to open a conversation with a single contact ma simply open the contact list of whatsapp and then chose the contact with share something.

Comment: So on iOS, using `BrowserService`, works for you? What is it that is not working?

Comment: yes I use browser service, on android works correctly but not for ios despite of I include in the .plist the whatsapp scheme.

Comment: Have you checked the iOS logs? With XCode->Devices select your device and run the app. Find out what it prints out when calling the service.

Comment: Jun 19 10:07:08 iPhone-di-Ws-Tech n_lex[1690] <Notice>: whatsapp://send?text=\134
Jun 19 10:07:08 iPhone-di-Ws-Tech n_lex(UIKit)[1690] <Notice>: -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "(null)" - error: "Invalid input URL"
Jun 19 10:07:08 iPhone-di-Ws-Tech n_lex[1690] <Notice>: Can't open url whatsapp://send?text=\134http://*MYURL*

Comment: Does it work for you when you add a string like `"whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!"`?

Comment: no, doesn't work too! Maybe the key on the .plist it's not correct or I have to add something else?  this is the error: -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!" - error: "The operation couldn\M-b\M^@\M^Yt be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"

Comment: The error 10814 seems to happen when there is no app to perform the task? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41139802/3956070)

Comment: Right! I use an iphone for test and I uninistalled whatsapp and the other apps. Sorry for the waste time for this banal problem and thank you so much!

Comment: anyway with the string hello word works but unfortunatelly not for my url! Maybe I have to encode it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, the error was in the prefix whatsapp://send?text=\ , I changed it in whatsapp://send?text= and it works.